# Notebook path can't be in DBFS?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Some of us are working with IDEs and trying to deploy notebooks (.py) files to dbfs. the problem I have noticed is when configuring jobs, those paths are not recognized.

notebook_path:
If I use this :

```
  dbfs:/artifacts/client-state-vector/0.0.0/bootstrap.py. 


Only absolute paths are currently supported. Paths must begin with '/'."
```

If I use this;

```
/dbfs/artifacts/client-state-vector/0.0.0/bootstrap.py

or 
/artifacts/client-state-vector/0.0.0/bootstrap.py
```

I get `Notebook not found`.

what could be the issue here?

I see from the Databricks's architecture that Notebooks are in Microsoft managed subscription whereas DBFS is in Customer's subscription. Could that be the reason (that Notebook task is only able to pick from the microsoft managed subscription)? e.g. The folders I created on the workspace level where I have some notebooks, do not show up in the DBFS browser, so I am beginning to think that could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notebooks aren't the files on file system - they are stored inside the control plane, not in the data plane where DBFS is located. If you want to execute notebook - you need to upload it via [Workspace API - import](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#import), or via [`databricks workspace import ...` command of databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html) or via [`databricks_notebook` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/notebook) of Databricks Terraform provider.  Only after that you will be able to refer it in the `notebook_path` parameter.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I suspected and wrote above. We uploaded it via the "Notebooks upload" task in Azure DevOps, earlier today and that made it work. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: You may consider using Databricks Repos to sync code: https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html. I have a demo that showing how to use it as part of DevOps CI/CD: https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-projects-demo.  Also you may look onto https://github.com/databrickslabs/cicd-templates if you have more IDE-oriented workflows

Comment: Thanks, will check them out. right now , we use Azure Devops to roll out to diff workspaces in diff environments. That includes standard devops tasks along with some powershell scripts with rest apis

Comment: yeah, but REST API is cumbersome to use. You can replace it with databricks-cli, or use terraform provider for deployments